# Alert is showing two times. how to restrict?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
<script language="Javascript">  

function test(myObject, flag)
{
if ( (flag) || ((event.keyCode == 59) || (event.which == 59)) || ((event.keyCode == 44) || (event.which == 44)))
{alert(myObject.value);}
}      
function closeWin()
{self.close();}      
</script>            

<form name='test'>          
<textarea  name='textareaName' cols='44' rows='3' onChange='test(this, true);' --onKeyPress='test(this);' onBlur='test(this, true);' ></textarea>                           
<input type='text' name='textName'>      
<input type='button' name='buttonName' onclick='closeWin();' value='Cancel'>
</form>
```

I have a problem: when input value (e.g: test;) into `textareaName` field, the test function is always run more one time. Please show me the way can run this only one time.

Comment: I rolled back a change which screwed up the formatting I did.

Comment: Yea, I rolled back a change too to go back to my fixes. Gah. If he keeps undoing the changes, im just giving up

Comment: And Dev undid all our changes. LOL. I give up.

Comment: @Moron - Yea same here, I just gave up

Comment: `Dev` knows his shit. You don't mess with his question.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are adding the `test` function to `onKeyPress` (so every key press), `onChange` (so every time it changes), and `onBlur` (whenever you move to another field)

It is doing exactly what you told it to do, you should remove one of the event handlers.